# How to use union in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

For example I have two select queries that return - 
first:

```
    A    |   B
------------------
    1    |   2
```

and second:

```
    A    |   B
------------------
    3    |   4
```

and I want to merge them so I get

```
    A    |   B
------------------
    1    |   2
    3    |   4
```

How can I do it with MySQL?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show a  minimum effort.

Comment: @JanDoggen Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select a, b from table1
union all
select a, b from table2
```

Comment: Using unions is pretty bad it always uses an temporary table or an myisam disk based temporary table if the result is to big or in some cases... and yes explain doenst show this.. union all also uses an filesort because sorting is needed..

Comment: Pretty bad compared to what alternative?